# If a 302 redirect is implemented, would the old site still be indexed?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, 302-redirect

If a 302 redirect is implemented, would the old site still be indexed?

I’m assuming as the redirect is in place, a user would not see the contact on the old page hence search/crawl bots would not be able to index the site or page either. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: This appears to be related to your [previous question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75775/want-to-redirect-a-domain-to-a-new-domain-using-301-or-302).  (By the way, this question is a better question because it is more specific and direct.)

Answer (score 3):

If you redirect a page to another page, then Google will no longer index the redirected page.   Implementing a redirect *removes* the content.

If you are moving a site from one domain to another without changing the content, you can use the [change of address](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) feature in Google Webmaster Tools.   When doing so, your new site will take the place of your old site in the Google search results.

Even when your new site has different content, but similar keywords, it may end up ranking well for some of the things that the old site ranked for.  A redirect from one site to the other will allow search engines to attribute reputation from the old site to the new site.   I'd recommend using 301 redirects rather than 302 redirects because Google is much more likely to pass authority when the redirect is permanent.

If you are removing content completely and not replacing it with something similar, then you will stop ranking for those keywords.  The only way to preserve rankings is to leave the old content up and still show it to users.

Comment: But, what in the exact case of an `302`, what if it actually is temporary? Does it get indexed, but low ranked and checked back every once in a while?

Comment: Temporary redirects occasionally cause Google to index the content of the new site but at the old URL.  Because they don't pass authority well, rankings are likely to be lower.   Whether you use 301 or 302 redirects, Google comes back and checks them frequently.

Comment: BIG +1 for the Change of address link you provided. My exact scenario!